# Prototype conversion ajax.updater

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have got a website that currenty uses prototype that im trying to get away from.  These are the only 3 functions that use it.

I have been trying all morning to convert these but as my understanding of jquery isnt great im so struggling.

```
function GetCountries() {    
  new Ajax.Updater('country_list','site_countries.php', {parameters: '&onchange=1', onComplete: GetRegions});
}


function GetRegions() {    
  new Ajax.Updater('region_list','site_regions.php', {parameters: '&regionID='+$('regionID').value+'&countryID='+$('countryID').value+'&onchange=1', onComplete: GetTowns});
}

function GetTowns() {
  new Ajax.Updater('town_list','site_towns.php', {parameters: '&regionID='+$('regionID').value+'&countryID='+$('countryID').value});
}
```

this is what i have come up with but it doesnt work:

```
function GetCountries() { 
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "site_countries.php",
    data: '&onchange=1',
    success: function( transport ){
        $('#country_list').html(transport.responseText)
        GetRegions
    }
});
}
```

the page that is calls just returns a select dropdown list that replaces one within span called country_list on the page then it calles GetRegions which does the same.

Any assistance would be greatly received!

Steve

Comment: Did you check what error it gives? Use FireBug if you re using Firefox and if using Chrome, just press `F12` to get developer options, there in console you can see what error it gives.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the way you are providing the `data` field might be the issue here.
Try something like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "site_countries.php",
    data: {onchange: 1},
    success: function( transport ){
        $('#country_list').html(transport.responseText)
        GetRegions
    }
});
```

OR

```
function GetCountries() { 
    $("#country_list").load("site_countries.php", {onchange: 1}, function(){
        // call your GetRegions() here
    });  
}
```

Comment: +1 for "The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed." - latter example is a perfect answer.

Comment: the 2nd one works but how would you do the 2nd one as it passes more info accross?

Comment: Basically `data` field is a JSON element in itself, so if there are more than one parameters say `parameter1=value1` and `parameter2=value2` then you can make it to be `{parameter1: value1, parameter2: value2}`